# Google Analytics Event Tracking Using Jquery click function

Tags: jquery, google-analytics, event-tracking

I'm attempting to call google analytics _trackEvent asynchronously from inside another function.

```
$('.buybtn_2').click(function() {

  if ($('.buybtn_2').html() == 'Add to Cart') {
    addCartQuote(quoteId);
    $('.buybtn_2').html('Checkout >');
    $('.quantity_2').html('<span class="warningSmall">Project Added</span>').fadeOut(1500);
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Parts', 'Add To Cart', 'In Stock', qtySelected]);            
  } else {
    var goTo = '/Cart/CartList.php';
    window.location = goTo;             
  }

  return false;             
});
```

The track event doesn't appear to be firing.  If I take the same exact code and just wrap it a doc ready then it works fine I see it fire in the firefox console.  I think that this is just a scope issue that I'm not dealing with properly?

Comment: do you get in the click function at all? have you tried putting a debugger statement just before the `_gaq.push` call to see if the problems lies else where?

Comment: The click function absolutely works that's not the issue and FireFox isn't throwing any errors about that _gaq line. Yes I've tested qtySelected to ensure it's an INT with an alert everything seems fine with that as well.

Comment: So it's absolutely a scope issue I can get firefox to thrown an error of _gaq.push is not a function.  The question is how to resolve.

Comment: this seams that your `_gaq` is not loaded or not available per scope... try `window._gaq` in the console, do you get something or is it `undefined`?

Comment: window._gaq.push does not throw an error so it exists but I still do not see the event track call in firebug like I do when track page view loads.  I did just see an event fire in my real time events screen in my analytics but I'm not sure if that's 100% reliable.  It stands to reason I should see the call in firebug

Comment: maybe trivial, but have you tried `window._gaq.push` only in the console? Or also in your code with all the parameters replacing the simple `_gaq.push`, does it then dispatches a request?

Comment: Yes confirmed it does.

Comment: actually I think I have this riddle solved.  This function cannot accept a variable event if the variable is properly set.  So when I just drop off the qtySelected from the end it then fires properly.  No idea what to say about that.

Comment: did you have a look at the API docs https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables maybe you need to explicitly define a custom variable I guess